# ORA-01858 FOR BEGINNER

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Pizza 
(
    pizza_id DECIMAL(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    date_available DATE NOT NULL,
    price DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE Topping 
(
    topping_id DECIMAL(12) NOT NULL,
    topping_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    pizza_id DECIMAL(12)
);

ALTER TABLE Topping
    ADD CONSTRAINT topping_pk PRIMARY KEY(topping_id);

ALTER TABLE Topping
    ADD CONSTRAINT Topping_pizza_fk
        FOREIGN KEY(pizza_id) REFERENCES Pizza(pizza_id);

INSERT INTO pizza (pizza_id, name, date_available, price) 
VALUES (1, 'Plain', CAST('27-Feb-2021' AS DATE), 6);
```

Error:

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

I cannot figure out which part is wrong, I'm just a beginner for SQL, it seems related with date, can someone help me?

Comment: There's typo in `date_avaliable`. Apart from that it runs well. See your code running at: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f7d5e49c5d6f8483e7a3a86ef84d1cd6

Comment: I didn't notice the Oracle error code. MySQL has more difficulty with this than just the typo.

Comment: @TheImpaler   However, my SQL does keep saying there's error with the date_avaliable, do you have any clue about this?

Comment: I corrected the "available", but this time it says Error report -
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected @KenWhite

Comment: `'27-Feb-2021'` doesn't appear to be any sort of date format that can be `CAST` to a date. Use proper dates like `'2021-02-27'` instead.

Comment: Works like a charm at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ed254bed9b05054918686cfbb72e455d), so it's something local to your site. I'm betting @KenWhite is right about the date cast - I suggest replacing `CAST('27-Feb-2021' AS DATE)` with `DATE '2021-02-27'`.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c7b4f/2). Don't use `CAST` to convert strings to dates. That's the only thing that looks off about your example. It may be using a different default date format than your string. Instead use `TO_DATE( '27-Feb-2021', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')` which converts a string to a date, or `DATE '2021-02-27'`, which is a date *literal* and only takes the yyyy-mm-dd format.

Additionally, I'd suggest using `NUMBER` instead of `DECIMAL` just because it's more standard in the Oracle world. And always use `VARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR`, which is officially discouraged.